# JDOM: How to avoid &#xD; in pretty printed output?

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtextpane, jdom

How do I avoid `&#xD;` in my XML output?

JDOM talks about this in the javadoc of the method [Format.setLineSeparator](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/Format.html#setLineSeparator(java.lang.String)).

For the sake of this question, please assume that I only get an XML document that I have to serialize. XML element texts might contain any combination of `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`, from a database, UI component, browser, program, etc.

Is it possible to configure JDOM to only write `\r\n`, and never `&#xD;`?

Is this a specialty of JDOM or do other XML libraries behave the same? Will have to check...

The only idea I have so far is to iterate the complete document and remove any occurence of `\r` in any text property of any element. If that is indeed my only option, I would also be interested in a correct and readable way of doing so.

Another idea i have is to clean the output: `xml.replace("&#xD;", "")`

### Example

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.setText("line 1\r\nline 2");
    //    pane.setText("line 1\nline 2");
    Element element = new Element("el");
    element.setText(pane.getText());

    Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
    format.setLineSeparator("\r\n");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    new XMLOutputter(format).output(new Document(element), writer);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
  }
```

### Output

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <el>line 1&#xD;
    line 2</el>
```

### Context

I ran into this because JTextPane.getText() sometimes returned text with just `\n`, and sometimes with `\r\n`. JTextPane also has some pretty crazy end of line logic. See [DefaultEditorKit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html) (search for `EndOfLineStringProperty`).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you [cite](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/Format.html#setLineSeparator(java.lang.String)) is pretty emphatic that the answer here is "no".

Anytime it sees a "\r" in the input string it will replace it with a "&#xD;". Using setLineSeparator just changes what "\n" gets converted to.

What happens if you call: `format.setLineSeparator(LineSeparator.NONE);`

Comment: Exactly, and I couldn't believe that this behavior is useful for anyone, so I was hoping that I missed something. Using any line separator other than "\r\n" will not get me windows separators in the output.